# Mailchimp API pending user does not receive mail

Tags: php, list, mailchimp

I'm registering users though a custom Drupal form and sending the data to the API.
The first time a user submits the form they are at status pending and receive the opt in mail accordingly.
The problem occurs when a user with status "unsubscribed" **resubscribes** to the list with the put request and changes the status to pending. The opt -in mail is not sent although with /lists/{list_id}/members i can see the mail as pending.

This is the php part that tries to resubscribe a mail though efforts with postman lead to the same behavior.

```
  private function tryToResubscribe($email, $lang_code){

    $connection = curl_init();
    curl_setopt(
      $connection,CURLOPT_URL,'https://' . 'us10' . '.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/' . $this->list_id . '/members/' . md5(strtolower($email))
    );
    curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
      'Content-Type: application/json',
      'Authorization: Basic ' . base64_encode('user:' . $this->api_key),
    ]);
    curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
    curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt(
      $connection,
      CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
      json_encode([
        'apikey' => $this->api_key,
        'email_address' => $email,
        'status' => $this->status,
      ])
    );
    $result = curl_exec($connection);
    $newRes = curl_getinfo($connection);
  }
```